# Why is the external JavaScript file not responding to AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This angularJS file does not display the value of the expression as" Full Name: John Doe"; instead it displays "Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}". What might I have missed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-controller="personController">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>

<script src="C:\Users\Vincent\Documents\Python\angularjs\StraightAngularJS\personController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>


<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-controller="personController">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>

<script src="personController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

*End of AngularJS file*

*Below is its external javaScript file: personController.js*

```
function personController($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John",
    $scope.lastName = "Doe",
    $scope.fullName = function() {
        return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: try using proper controller constructor per docs. Support for global functions has been dropped. Also better to use relative path to your script file

Comment: Before you start wondering why the script doesn't work, make sure it is loaded at the first place! If you are using Chrome, check the  `sources` tab to find whether your file `personController.js` is there. Btw, why do you have two `body` tag there?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because you're including your script tag to the app `<script src="personController.js"></script>` outside of the scope of the div containing your `ng-app`.

As shown in this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z1Lhj571/), the code does work correctly, so there's nothing else wrong.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also learnt, relative file location of external jsp file not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be due to browser restriction for CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). 
To know more about CORS, read - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Using Chrome you can disable the security check by launching Chrome with the following parameter, which will allow the browser to load files from different domains:

```
chrome --disable-web-security
```

If you are trying to load the controller from local disk.

```
<script src="C:\Users\[user-name]\Documents\Python\angularjs\StraightAngularJS\personController.js"></script>
```

Launching Chrome with the following parameter is required:

```
chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

But please note that, this is not the recommended way and you better use a http server to load your resources.